# Unsupported Media Type with POST

Tags: java, http, post, curl, jersey

I use curl to send a `HTTP POST` request using this:

```
   curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.3581,-71.0636]}}' http://localhost:8180/GoogleMapsLoadingTest/GoogleMapsErp/EQUI/
```

I am calling this `jersey` method:

```
  @POST
@Path("/{objtype}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUsingPost(@PathParam("objtype") String objtype,String objstr)
{
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj=null;
    try {
        obj=(JSONObject) parser.parse(objstr);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject geo=(JSONObject) obj.get("geometry");
            ...
            ...
}
```

I get this error in `terminal`:

```
 HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Content-Length: 0
 Date: Mon, 05 May 2014 05:52:02 GMT
```

I get this error in my Eclipse console:

```
  SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class org.json.simple.JSONObject, and Java type  
  class org.json.simple.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
  The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
  application/json ->
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
   */* ->
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```